# Encountered error while Defining __asm Blocks as C Macros

Tags: c, visual-c++, reverse, obfuscation

When I try to define a multi-instruction shared byte obfuscating code with c macro, there is an error when compiling, the error codes are C2414 and C2400
If the c macro definition is not used, it can be compiled successfully

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define test __asm{\
__asm jmp $+5\
}

#define test1 __asm{\
__asm _emit 0xeb\
__asm _emit 0xff\
__asm _emit 0xc0\
__asm _emit 0x48\
}

int main()
{
    test1;
}
```

How can I use this obfuscating code inside a c macro?

Comment: I may be mistaken, but that \ is basically escaping the `\n`, making it a oneliner. So, the result would be: `__asm _emit 0xeb__asm _emit...`. Maybe add a space before that \?

Comment: As noted by @RefugnicEternium macros can't have multiple lines. The line-continuation at the end will lead to macro-expansion being only a single line for the compiler to parse. Most compilers have a way to stop after preprocessing, so you can see what macros expand to. I suggest you use that when having problems with macros.

Comment: Given that you are defining an `__asm{}` macro, do you need the `asm`  keyword on each line as well?

Comment: I also think you need a semi-colon after each `__asm` instruction, optional only for the last one

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/inline/asm?view=msvc-170) then multiple `__asm` on a single line should be ok. But after compiling your code in MSVC, the actual problem reported is:

> (15): error C2059: syntax error: 'bad suffix on number'

And then we realize that your macro expands to `__asm _emit 0xeb__asm _emit 0xff` and so on, where `0xeb__asm` is gibberish. Adding a space to each row like `0xeb \` made your code compile cleanly.